# host not found in upstream error caused by docker-compose

Tags: docker, unix, docker-compose, dockerfile

tldr-version: I have no idea whats causing this error. im pretty sure its not the line endings because i changed them manually with notepad++ (unless i need to change more than entrypoint.sh because thats all i changed the line endings on).

###### original post below.

I have no idea what is causing this error caused when i do docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build into my command line i get the following output

```
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
Starting mygoattheend-copy_app_1 ... done
Starting mygoattheend-copy_proxy_1 ... done
Attaching to mygoattheend-copy_app_1, mygoattheend-copy_proxy_1
app_1    | exec /scripts/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
proxy_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
mygoattheend-copy_app_1 exited with code 1
proxy_1  | 2022/11/03 18:51:39 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
mygoattheend-copy_proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

Other examples of errors that appear when i search for ***nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9*** online suggest the problem is due to missing -depends_on: so ive included my docker-compose file below but i followed the tutorial perfectly and his worked fine. And my docker-compose-deploy has its
-depends_on:

my full docker compose is below

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
```

My full docker-compose-deploy.yml is below

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=samplesecretkey123
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  static_data:
```

the image below is my full directory

[image]

The error does mention that it can't find app, which i copy with the main dockerfile (not the one in the proxy folder)

My main dockerfile is below.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/*
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/
RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

what could be causing this error?

what other info do you need to work it out?

im following this tutorial. im at the very end https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh1ynJGJuT8

##### update 1 (adding extra info)

my proxy/default.conf is below

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location /static {
    alias /vol/static;
  }
  location / {
    uwsgi_pass app:8000;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

my proxy/dockerfile is below

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 755 /vol/static

USER nginx
```

##### update 2

this is my whole project uploaded to github https://github.com/tgmjack/help

#### update 3

editing the line endings in vscode didnt appear to work.

[image]

#### update 4

new dockerfile trying dos2unix

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers dos2unix
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp
RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/*
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/
RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user
CMD ["dos2unix", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

but i still get the same error.

##### update 5

ok so i changed the eol of entrypoint.sh manually with notepad++ but i still get the same error.
do i need to apply this to more than just entrypoint.sh?

Comment: I see the error message references the nginx configuration. Can you include the contents of `proxy/default.conf` and `proxy/Dockerfile`?

Comment: its been added :)

Comment: Typically I'll see this error on nginx configurations which use an upstream to define the host to connect to. However your configuration has no `upstream { ... }` part, so I don't know what could cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in this setup.

#### DOS line endings

The first problem is the use of DOS line endings on the entrypoint. Here's what I see when I use `od` to get a character-by-character dump of the files:

```
$ od -c scripts/entrypoint.sh | head -n 2
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \r  \n  \r  \n   s   e   t
0000020       -   e  \r  \n  \r  \n   p   y   t   h   o   n       m   a
```

The issue is that after `#!/bin/sh`, we have `\r\n`, when we should have just `\n`. This is a DOS-style line ending, but Linux expects just a `\n`. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

I used a program called dos2unix to replace those lines:

```
$ dos2unix scripts/entrypoint.sh 
dos2unix: converting file scripts/entrypoint.sh to Unix format...
```

(VS code can do this too - [here's how.](https://medium.com/@csmunuku/windows-and-linux-eol-sequence-configure-vs-code-and-git-37be98ef71df))

When I run it, I get a new error:

```
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
app_1    |     main()
app_1    |   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
app_1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
app_1    |     utility.execute()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
app_1    |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
app_1    |     self._setup(name)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
app_1    |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
app_1    |     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
app_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
app_1    |   File "/app/app/settings.py", line 31, in <module>
app_1    |     ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS.split(',')) # .split(",") = incase multiple so we seperate them with a comma
app_1    | AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

#### Wrong variable referenced in settings file

I edited the file `app/app/settings.py`, and changed this line

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS.split(','))
```

to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV.split(','))
```

After this, I found this worked.

#### Nginx

The nginx configuration turned out to be fine. The issue was that the app died, so nginx couldn't do a DNS lookup to find the IP address of the app container. Fixing the app container also fixes nginx.

Comment: i tried fixing the line endings in vs-code like the tutorial said but it didnt seem to work. i'm gunna check out dos2unix tomorow, see if that works

Comment: so for step 1 all i had to do was install dos2unix and replace the last line of my dockerfile with CMD ["dos2unix", "entrypoint.sh"]?  because i still get the same error...  ive updated my github with the current version.

Comment: can i ask, are you on windows? every single example i see on youtube is with mac.  is it because im on windows?

Comment: you were right, i just had to apply all the same changes to every file in my scripts and proxy folder